# How to get host Name From IP Address or MacAddress which are connected to my wifi

Tags: ios, network-programming, hostname, local-network

I want to get the mac Address,IP Address,Host Name, device Name And Brand Name of the devices which are connected to my wifi router.I will Get all these except the host name.

I have tried MMLAnscan,AFNetworking,LANScanMaster,etc it will provide me all the details except host name

```
+(NSString *)getHostFromIPAddress:(NSString*)ipAddress {
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    //"www.kame.net", "http"
    int errorStatus = getaddrinfo([ipAddress cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NULL, &hints, &result);
    //NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of NSASCIIStringEncoding
    if (errorStatus != 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    CFDataRef addressRef = CFDataCreate(NULL, (UInt8 *)result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
    if (addressRef == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    CFHostRef hostRef = CFHostCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, addressRef);
    if (hostRef == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    CFRelease(addressRef);

    BOOL succeeded = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostNames, NULL);
    if (!succeeded) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray *hostnames = [NSMutableArray array];

    CFArrayRef hostnamesRef = CFHostGetNames(hostRef, NULL);
    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < [(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef count]; currentIndex++) {
        [hostnames addObject:[(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef objectAtIndex:currentIndex]];
        NSLog(@"hostt:%@",hostnames);
    }
    NSLog(@"hostname:%@",hostnames[0]);
    return hostnames[0];
}
```

I want hostnames of the devices which are connected to my wifi.